# Where should a function be called containing Collection data from a Meteor subscription as well as jQuery DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, spacebars

I'm new to web applications and stumbled across a problem in Meteor I haven't found a good solution to (please let me know if the answer already exists on https://stackoverflow.com/).

I have a `profileEdit` Template page I want to update with default values from the `Meteor.users` Collection as it is rendered. This works fine using Template helpers for `<input type="text">`, but for:

`<select class="form-control" name="profileNamePrefix" id="profileNamePrefix">`

and

`<label><input type="radio" name="profileGender">Male</label>`

I had to use jQuery DOM manipulation to get it to work (this could be my real problem):

**JS**

```
// GLOBAL FUNCTIONS
updateSelectedOption = function() {
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
    var currentUser = Meteor.users.findOne(currentUserId);
    var profileTitleOptions = $('#profileNamePrefix').children();
    var status = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < profileTitleOptions.length; i++) {
      if (currentUser && currentUser.profile &&
          currentUser.profile.title === profileTitleOptions[i].value) {
        profileTitleOptions[i].selected = true;
        statue = true;
        break;
      };
    };
    return status;
};

updateCheckedRadio = function() {
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
    var currentUser = Meteor.users.findOne(currentUserId);
    var profileGenderRadios = $('input:radio[name="profileGender"]');
    var status = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < profileGenderRadios.length; i++) {
      if (currentUser && currentUser.profile && 
          currentUser.profile.gender === $(profileGenderRadios[i].closest('label'))[0].innerText) {
        $(profileGenderRadios[i]).attr("checked", "checked");
        status = true;
        break;
      };
    };
    return status;
};
```

These functions work, but I don't know where to place the function calls. Since they get data from the `Meteor.users` Collection , they should be called as helpers (as discussed [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/837)):

**JS**

```
Template.profileEdit.helpers({
  'selectOptionIfTitleIs': function() {
    return updateSelectedOption();
  },
  'checkRadioIfGenderIs': function() {
    return updateCheckedRadio();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<template name="profileEdit">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="profileNamePrefix" id="profileNamePrefix">
            <option value="Mr">Mr.</option>
            <option value="Ms">Ms.</option>
            <option value="Mrs">Mrs.</option>
            <option value="Dr">Dr.</option>
            <option value="Prof">Prof.</option>
            <option value="Sir">Sir</option>
          </select>
          {{#if selectOptionIfTitleIs}}
          {{/if}}
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.col-sm-2 -->
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="profileGender">Male</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="profileGender">Female</label>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.col-sm-2 -->
      {{#if checkRadioIfGenderIs}}
      {{/if}}
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

This works when the page is refreshed, but when it is redirected from the Navigation bar via `Router.go('profileEdit');` it does not update the selected/checked values because the jQuery calls are empty (I'm suspecting this is because they are performed before the HTML is properly rendered). Adding the function calls to `onRendered()` solves this, but doesn't work when the page is refreshed.

**JS**

```
Template.profileEdit.onRendered(function() {
  updateSelectedOption();
  updateCheckedRadio();
});
```

Is there a way to unify these two function calls and keep the form updated when the page is redirected as well as refreshed? Any tips on how to implement the update functionality in a nicer way in Meteor is also appreciated.

### Edited

After a bit of thinking and some help from Peter's solution I ended up solving this issue by using only Spacebars and Template helpers instead:

**HTML**

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Title</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="profileNamePrefix" id="profileNamePrefix">
        {{#each namePrefixes}}
          <option value="{{value}}" selected="{{prefixIsSelected}}">{{name}}</option>
        {{/each}}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-2 -->
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      {{#each genders}}
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="profileGender" checked="{{genderIsChecked}}">{{name}}</label>
        </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-2 -->
</form>
```

**JS**

```
Template.profileEdit.helpers({
  namePrefixes: [{
      name: "Mr.",
      value: "Mr"
    },
    {
      name: "Ms.",
      value: "Ms"
    },
    {
      name: "Mrs.",
      value: "Mrs"
    },
    {
      name: "Dr.",
      value: "Dr"
    },
    {
      name: "Prof.",
      value: "Prof"
    },
    {
      name: "Sir",
      value: "Sir"
    }
  ],
  genders: [{name: "Male"},
            {name: "Female"}
  ],
  'prefixIsSelected': function() {
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
    var currentUser = Meteor.users.findOne(currentUserId);
    return currentUser && currentUser.profile && currentUser.profile.title === this.value;
  },
  'genderIsChecked': function() {
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
    var currentUser = Meteor.users.findOne(currentUserId);
    return currentUser && currentUser.profile && currentUser.profile.gender === this.name;
  }
});
```

This way the form updates properly when redirected or refreshed. The only question that remains is if I would be forced to update something through jQuery that relies on a data Collection, where would one call that code from? Or is it always possible to find a 'Meteor way' using Spacebars?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template helpers that return true/false directly in the template.
The following explanation assumes  your current data context (`this`) is your user or profile which has the data:

**Radio Buttons and Check Boxes**

```
<input name="gender" type="radio" checked="{{genderCheck 'male'}}"/> Male
```

and then declare a template helper:

```
genderCheck: function(value) {
    return (this.profile.gender == value);
}
```

The disabled attribute works in the same way. Blaze (Meteor Templates) removes obsolete checked and disabled attributes when delivering the DOM.

**Selects**

```
<select name="salutation">
  <option selected="{{checkSalutation 'Mr'}}">Mr</option>
  <option selected="{{checkSalutation 'Mrs'}}">Mrs</option>
  ..
</select>
```

And the helper:

```
checkSalutation: function(value) {
    return (this.profile.salutation == value);
}
```

If you have an `{{#each ..}}` loop you can pass the element or an attribute of the element to the helper if you like. If you don't you can still access it with `this` inside the Javascript code. Template helpers refer to `this` as the current data context (e.g. inside a loop the current loop element).

Comment: Thanks Peter, I ended up doing something similar using Spacebars and Template helpers, which solved my problem and cleaned up the code significantly. I'm still wondering though if I would be forced to update something through jQuery which relies on a data Collection, where would you call that code from? Or is it always possible to find a 'Meteor way' using Spacebars?

Comment: I would limit DOM manipulations using JQuery only to the `Template.name.rendered` function and the `Template.name.events` (there are exceptions to this..). Reactivity is sometimes hard to completely understand. Basically every helper accessing the database (via collections) or the Session (yes, the session is also reactive) is re-executed whenever the underlying data is changed. Additionally you can declare other things reactive by using https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var